# Why was my answer with 8+ upvotes deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I posted an answer to this Stack Overflow question: ["Class does not contain a constructor taking 0 parameters"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483009/class-does-not-contain-a-constructor-taking-0-parameters)

Why was my answer deleted?

[image: Why was this deleted ?]

Comment: I'm guessing the first line was the only part that existed when the flag was raised, and possibly it was the only part that was visible when Will handled it. The moral of the story: FGITW at your own peril.

Comment: That doesn't make sense; even if it got flagged in the first five minutes, it was still fully fleshed out when deleted.

Comment: Status-completed by the looks of it.

Comment: It took me a full minute at least to figure out what FGITW means ...

Comment: @Oded If it was edited within the first 5 minutes it wouldn't be in the history.

Comment: @Servy - True enough. I will give the OP the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Yes, but if you delete a post right from the flag queue, it might still show in its first revision if you haven't reloaded the page until then.

Comment: thnx everyone!!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know you were still editing when I hit that flag. My apologies for the error.

Comment: If the answer wasn't an answer when you got to the flag, you were correct to delete it surely @Won't? Whether the OP was editing or not. I've learnt my lesson in the past about flagging answers within the first 5 minutes but if someone's flagging and you get to it that quickly then you're perfectly correct to delete. The OP editing has nothing to do with it. Though they go on to post a good (looks like great) answer they shouldn't be posting a non-answer stub at the beginning if they don't want to risk this happening.

Comment: @ben: there were 20 minutes between the last edit and deletion. 25-ish since the first post time. The OP was long done editing by then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It may very well be human error following a flag.

Someone has flagged your answer as not an answer and the moderator that dealt with it may have made an error.

However, you do need to be sure to post a full answer if you don't want it flagged in this manner.

I have now undeleted the answer.